# How can I split a string with "/" as the separator?

Tags: uipath

I'm working on some code on UiPath, trying to split this string "2700/30" so that i get 2700 and 30 seperated.

Tried this "2700/30 “.split(”/"c)(0) but doesn't work, i get my data from excel file, before storing this data into variables i use .toString

PS: Error, says that it can't convert from string to char

myvarA = row.Item(0).ToString

ps : row.Item(0).ToString contains "2700/30"

I need to get this :

myvarA = row.Item(0).ToString
myvarB = row.Item(0).ToString

as myvarA = 2700 and myvarB = 30

Comment: have you tried "//"

Comment: i'm using UiPath, here's what i'm looking to do alarmCode.Split("/"c)(0) = row.Item(1).ToString

Comment: DrBwts, don't unterstand what you mean?

Comment: What result do you get? Is an error thrown? "it doesn't work" doesn't tell us much :)

Comment: Yes Mads T, sorry about that. The error, says that it can't convert from string to char

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are in some kind of loop since you have a var called `row`.
You also mention Excel, so I assume it is a row of a `DataTable` you are working on.

`row(0).ToString` gives you the data of first column of said DataTable as a String. Adjust that `0` to whatever column number you need.

The `String.Split` method returns an array of strings, so you can directly ask for the index you need in the same way.

Using the above knowledge you can use the following two Assigns:

```
myvarA = row(0).ToString.Split("/"c)(0)
```

and

```
myvarB = row(0).ToString.Split("/"c)(1)
```